# How set up Prometheus Operator with Grafana to enable basic Kubernetes monitoring

Tags: grafana, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator

I followed a bunch of tutorials on how to monitor Kubernetes with prometheus and Grafana
All referring to a [deprecated helm operator](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus)

According to the tutorials Grafana comes out of the box complete with cluster monitoring.
In practice Grafana is not installed with the chart

```
helm install prometheus-operator stable/prometheus -n monitor
```

nor is it installed with the newer community repo

```
helm install prometheus-operator prometheus-community/prometheus -n monitor
```

I installed the Grafana chart independently

```
helm install grafana-operator grafana/grafana -n monitor
```

And through the UI tried to connect using inner cluster URLs

prometheus-operator-server.monitor.svc.cluster.local:80

prometheus-operator-alertmanager.monitor.svc.cluster.local:80

the UI test indicates success but produces no metrics.

Is there a ready made Helm operator with out of the box Grafana?
How can Grafana interact with Prometeus?

Comment: This can be useful i have used it https://medium.com/the-metricfire-blog/monitoring-kubernetes-tutorial-using-grafana-and-prometheus-f106091534fb

Answer (score 3):

You've used the wrong charts. Currently the project is named `kube-prometheus-stack`:
https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack

If you look at `values.yaml` you'll notice switches for everything, including prometheus, all the exporters, grafana, all the standard dashboards, alerts for kubernetes and so on. It's all installed by one chart. And it's all linked together out of the box.

They only additional thing you might need is an Ingress/ELB for grafana, prometheus, and alertmanager to be able to open them without port-forwarding (don't forget to add ouath2-proxy or smth else cause it's all opened with no password by default).

Answer (score -2):

I wouldn't bother, look at PaaS like Datadog, NewRelic etc. What you are describing becomes a costly nightmare at scale. It's just not worth the hassle for what you get ihmo.

Comment: I thought of this but, i'm working on POC and need minimal functionality to gauge nodes. + I provision EKS and deprovision using terraform every run even in production

Comment: seems like the elastic operator or helm is the way to go